# Why does AWS cli give me InvalidAccessKeyId error, when Im able to use the same creds for s3cmd?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS cli returns me

`A client error (InvalidAccessKeyId) occurred when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

However, I'm able to hadoop distcp as well as s3md using the exact same credentials. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that runs into this issue - check your environment variables. Apparently the CLI uses those before using anything in the credentials file.

I'm on Mac, so removing the offending env variables from my ~/.profile file did the trick.

Comment: This is good, but would be great if you can list the offending vars. At least the ones that you removed. Right now I am facing this issue and have no clue which env var to remove to even try this approach.